# High CPU Utilization and Crash When Running amd64 Docker Container for Image Processing on Mac with M3 Chip

Tags: docker, macos, containers

I am developing a Node.js application that utilizes the `sharp` library for image processing. The application is containerized using Docker (actually using Rancher or Orbstack depending; NOT Docker Desktop), and I've been running it without any issues on machines with Intel chips. However, when I attempt to run ( --platform linux/amd64) the same container on a Mac equipped with an M3 chip, I encounter a significant issue: the container's CPU utilization spikes to 100% during image processing tasks, and upon subsequent runs, it crashes entirely. This behavior is consistently reproducible, and it does not occur on Intel-based systems where the container remains stable and the tests complete successfully.

**Environment Details:**

- Operating System: MacOS (Version for M3 chip)
- Docker Version: 24.0.7-rd, build 72ffacf
- Node Version: 16.20
- Sharp Library Version: 0.32.6
- Container Architecture: amd64 (using Rosetta 2 for emulation on M3)
- Container type: Linux Amazon 2

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Start the Docker container on the Mac with the M3 chip.
2. Run the image processing tests using the `sharp` library.
3. Observe the CPU utilization (spikes to 100%) and note any crashes on subsequent runs.

**Expected Behavior:**

The container should process images without maxing out CPU utilization and without crashing, similar to its performance on Intel-based Macs.

**Actual Behavior:**

On a Mac with an M3 chip, the container's CPU utilization hits 100% during image processing tasks, and the container crashes on subsequent test runs.

**Question:**

Has anyone experienced similar issues with Docker containers on Macs with M3 chips, especially when running amd64 containers under Rosetta 2?

Any insights, experiences, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I am particularly interested in understanding if this is a known limitation with Rosetta 2 emulation for amd64 containers or if there are specific adjustments that can be made to the Docker configuration to address this problem. Also wondering whether if there is another way to triage and generate logs that shed light on the crashes.

I have added -prof flag to the node application to profile it. And the output isn't really much different between the container running on Intel and the one running on Apple silicon.

Comment: Please limit questions to a single question per post. See [help/on-topic] for more details.

Comment: Sure thing. I edited down to one primary question.